# NOTICE TO DEFENDANTS ABS-CBN Corporation, et al. v. Cinesilip.net, et al

Tags: united-states, civil-law, civil-procedure

My computer was showing some-pop that your computer is infected call on this number etc.. which is scam I know that but a few days back I was reading an article on domains and hosting and I click on url((Link) it transferred me to a website which shows me this message

ABS-CBN Corporation, et al. v. Cinesilip.net, et al.

On April 4, 2017, in the United States District Court for the District of Florida, ABS-CBN Corporation, filed a Complaint For Damages and Injunctive Relief against Cinesilip.net, et al. The filings and orders in this matter are available below.

NOTICE TO DEFENDANTS
If you fail to respond to this complaint, judgment by default will be entered against you for the relief demanded in the complaint.

To prevent this from happening you must file a response with the court clerk or administrator within 21 days of the date this message was posted. Your response must be in proper form and have proof of service on the plaintiffs' attorney, Stephen M. Gaffigan, P.A, 401 East Las Olas Boulevard, Suite 130-453, Ft. Lauderdale, Florida 33301.

4/4/2017    COMPLAINT FOR DAMAGES AND INJUNCTIVE RELIEF

do I have to go to court to ask them? I googled it and showed that some domains were sued I don't have any domain I was redirected to website is it scam or do i have to do something

Comment: I have removed a criminal law tag that is inapplicable to this question and added a United States tag and a civil procedure tag and removed a small-claims court tag that does not apply.  Do you believe that you are one of the Defendants in this action? If so, why? A PACER search can determine who the parties are in the case.

Answer (score 2):

This is a real case and the parties to it can be found [here](https://www.law360.com/cases/58e3d7c529ae53494e000001). If you are a party to this action, you should pay attention, if you are not, you can ignore it. The case number is No. 0:2017cv60650.

A preliminary injunction was granted by default in the case [on April 28, 2017](http://law.justia.com/cases/federal/district-courts/florida/flsdce/0:2017cv60650/504109/25/).

One of the many defendants inquired about the case by telephone but did not enter a timely appearance in the case.

Default judgment was entered on the entire case against all defendants [on July 11, 2017](https://www.plainsite.org/dockets/34siqcxok/florida-southern-district-court/abscbn-corporation-et-al-v-cinesilipnet-et-al/).

Generally speaking, a default judgment can only be set aside within six months after it is entered under Federal Rule of Civil Procedure 60(b). To do so, one must show either a lack of proper service of process or show some form of excusable neglect and a meritorious defense to the claim in a motion supported by an affidavit filed in that court case. And, if the defendant is an entity, the motion must be filed by a lawyer on behalf of the entity.